# Scrolling SWT Browser to a specific element

Tags: java, browser, swt

I'm using the Browser component of SWT and setText() method to view HTML files in my application.
Now I want to scroll the window to a specific element within the current page.
The HTML document contains some headings, some paragraphs and graphics.
The element to scroll to is in that case the id of a heading (h1...h6).

I built the following method with "embedded" JavaScript code to do this task:

```
public static String scrollToElement(String id) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append("var elem = document.getElementById('" + id + "');");
  builder.append("if (!!elem && elem.scrollIntoView) {");
  builder.append("  elem.scrollIntoView();");
  builder.append("}");
  return builder.toString();
}

boolean b = browser.execute(JavaScriptBuilder.scrollToElement("headingID1"));
```

The method returns true so I think that the JS code is correct but the Browser window doesn't scroll. The focus is still on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript appears to be correct and is working for me, but maybe try to simplify it to:

```
document.getElementById('myId').scrollIntoView();
```

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);

    browser.setText("<div style='height: 500px;'></div><div id='myId'>TEST</div>");

    display.timerExec(1000, () -> {
        System.out.println(browser.execute("document.getElementById('myId').scrollIntoView();"));
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

---

Also, are you sure the element exists at the time of execution?

Comment: Yes the element exists. I also checked the correct execution by inserting alert lines. Are you sure that the focus is moved and not only the text is selected? Does it work if you try to scroll to an element which is not in the visible window because of an very complex page? I have for example a 400K document and want to scroll to a heading in the "middle".

Comment: If the purpose of the `timerExec()` is to wait for the document to be loaded you should rather use a `ProgressListener` and execute the Javascript  when the `completed()` event occurs.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Of course, if you'd implement this properly, you should use the `ProgressListener`, this is just a simple test example though.

Comment: Baz: No, it's the same effect - the focus is still on top of the window.

Rüdiger: I thouhgt that setText(...) blocks the execution until the content is set completely. Is this not correct?